Django Custom admin template
I changed the admin site index template in Django like this:
admin.site.index_template = "admin/list-aprovals.html"

but how can i send my model datas this page or can i add a custom view for this url:
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

So, I want to work with the existing django admin, but I only want to change the template and see my models in this special template, but with the original admin app. Is this possible in Django? How do I solve this problem?
I tried custom app but i want to use original contrib admin.

First: Make sure you have the admin listed in your INSTALLED_APPS.
Second: Register your model to the admin within your admin.py with
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
admin.site.register(MyModel)

This should be enough. If you plan on doing more tinkering with that admin site I recommend the following (more here). It is basically the same as above, but allows for more configuration lateron:
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)

Third: By default every superuser (User.is_superuser == True) has all permissions! Meaning a superuser can access the admin site and see all of your registered Models (Most likely inkluding Users and Groups).
By default every staffuser (User.is_staff == True) does NOT have all permissions! He has no permissions but can access the admin site. You would want to give this staffuser only the read write delete and change permissions to MyModel. This can be done via the superuser and the admin panel, or can be done via code on creation of the staffuser.
Fourth: Make sure your custom template (list-aprovals.html) extends the base_site.
<!-- list-aprovals.html -->
   {% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

   {% block content %}
   <!-- Your custom content here -->
   {% endblock %}

This gives your site the look of the admin site. Obviously now the logic is not handled which Models show up and which not. That is probably quite some heavy logic to rebuild so I would reconsider writing such custom template at all. If you need to rebuild it, I would copy the default index_template and work my way from there.

Thank you very much for your answer. I tried this but changed only right side panel page. I want to use my admin page with siderbarmenu but just i need to send model datas this admin template. How can i do this ? So can i add custom view this template ?

Thanks again @Tarquinius. I added a view function, i added a "index.html"  and i solved my problem. My view like this :
def custom_admin_index(request):
# Admin site context'ini alın
context = admin.site.each_context(request)
app_list = site.get_app_list(request)
context.update({
'title': _('Site administration'),
'app_list': app_list,
})
return render(request, 'admin/index.html', context)
admin.site.index = custom_admin_index

Glad it works now. I hope it was useful to you.
